# Lizmap unable to load maps that need authemtification after updating from 3.3.3 to 3.3.10

Tags: qgis-server, lizmap

I have a running Lizmap v. 3.3.3. instance that uses PostgreSQL for authentification.
I would like to update to a newer version v.3.3.10 and followed exactly the [update instructions](https://docs.lizmap.com/3.1/en/install/upgrade.html#upgrading-from-3-0-to-the-3-1-version).

When I now go to the new 3.3.10 site, all projects are there, but I'm only able to load the public maps (maps that do not need an authentification). When I log in, all my projects are there, but I cannot load the maps (I get an dark screen with the Lizmap logo indicating, that the maps going to be loaded - but nothing happens). When I change the access level to 'anonymous', the same project is loaded without issues.

```
unzulässige Anfrage(ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end
of transaction block(SELECT "ug"."login", "ug"."id_aclgrp" FROM "jacl2_user_group" AS "ug" 
WHERE  "ug"."login"  = 'admin'))    /var/www/lizmap-web-client-3.3.10/lib/jelix/plugins/db/pgsql
/pgsql.dbconnection.php 180
```

The same query executed in the lizmap database (with DBeaver) gives a valid result.
The connection to the lizmap-database works, since the login is written into the log_detail table.
All the access rights at file and directory level are set identical to the working v.3.3.3 instance.

Since I know, this is a very specific topic I also openend an [issue at the Lizmap github](https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues/1789) account.
But maybe someone has an idea or encountered the same problem.

Comment: Your link to documentation is old. Please use https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/install/upgrade.html#upgrading-from-lizmap-3-x-versions

Comment: Merci, You're right, I've followed the new upgrade description '3.0 versions to upper' that's provided in Your link. But newertheless I end up with the error and behavoir described above.